How to determine every Address Lookup Table (ALT) a Solana wallet has authority over
I'm currently working on a Solana project in Javascript where I need to identify all Address Lookup Tables (ALTs) that my wallet has authority over. The goal is to programmatically fetch a list of the ALTs addresses. Using solscan I can easily determine a transaction in which a ALT was created but viewing the instructions in which I can then see the public key associated with that ALT, but when dealing with a wallet that has thousands of transactions and has generated an immense amount of ALTs this becomes rather difficult to do. My goal is to be able to deactivate and close all lookup tables that have been created by the wallet. I have been able to successfully do this but only by providing the corresponding public key to each ALT manually. I want to be able to extract all public keys to every ALT that my wallet has authority over. Any tips or pointer on how to do this? As scraping all of my transaction has led me to many errors.

Call getProgramAccounts for the program AddressLookupTab1e1111111111111111111111111 and a memory comparison filter at byte offset 22 with the 32 byte authority public key.
Here is an example in Java, but this call is available in web3js as well.

I don't have enough reputation to cast a upvote but this worked perfectly!!!!!!!! Thank you so much for the help.
